# "thus" at end of sentence

Tags: word-order, conjunctions

Is it (grammatically) correct to put “thus” at the end of a sentence, like in this example?

> Most properties carry over directly. We only need to discuss them for one case thus.

I know that I could move thus to the beginning: “Thus we only need to discuss them for one case.”
I try to not overuse such conjunctions at the beginning of sentences, as for me, it seems to disrupt the “flow”.

How about “hence” instead of “thus”, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When *thus* means "therefore", it normally shouldn't be at the end. In that sense, it can often be replaced with *hence*.

When it means "in this manner", it's perfectly fine at the end.

Comment: You can certainly put some equivalents such as *therefore* at the end (normally preceded by a pause in speech, or a comma in writing). So although your answer would be appropriate if this were being asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (where querents usually only really want to know "standard" usage), I think on ELU it would be worth exploring *why* the final position doesn't work at all well with ***thus*** (perhaps it's simply because of potential confusion with the other meaning).

Comment: You say: “In that sense, it can often be replaced with hence.”
Is it OK then to end the sentences with “hence”?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Hmm I have added "normally". I'm not sure I can explain why, though (can you?). And I can't really think of an example of *thus* "therefore" properly used at the end of a sentence; do you have an example?

Comment: @Sebastian: *Hence* is normally not used at the end. Perhaps it is possible under certain circumstances, but that is not standard.

Comment: Well, all that's happening is we're moving an adverbial word/clause (from its "normal" position at the start) to the end of the utterance. The acceptability of this process ranges from *very* normal (e.g. - ***actually, then***) thru "unusual" (e.g. - ***hence, thus***) to "totally weird" (e.g. - ***so***, when it means ***therefore***). But there's obviously not going to be a grammatical rule governing this process that specifically defines certain usages as "valid", and others not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't think that is obvious at all, but I am unable to supply such a rule in this case, if it exists. I still think *thus* "therefore" and *hence* "therefore" at the end are worse than merely unusual, though.

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty more adverbial terms in the general area of "causal relationships". For example, I think I'd put ***in that case*** somewhere in between ***actually, then*** and ***hence, thus*** in terms of whether they can be successfully relocated to the *end* of the utterance. But it really is hard to see how any kind of rule could be formulated defining exactly where the "acceptable / unacceptable" boundary should be placed. More useful would be some idea of *why* some words go at one end of the scale, and some at the other (I've absolutely no idea why this might be though! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It is hard to see, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist! Not that I'm saying it *does* exist.

Comment: Well, I stand by the substance of my first comment. Somewhat paradoxically, I started off saying that on ELU we should expect something more than just *This is/isn't a valid / normal usage*, but our subsequent comments imply that you think there might be more behind the issue than me (i.e. - you think there might be an actual "rule" somewhere in this area). I may be moved to post a bounty on it later, to see if anyone else knows any more than we do about the whys and wherefores of the usage.

Comment: "thus" can go at the end, deictically. [ahem] I think one has to think pragmatically (pragmatics, in linguistics).

Comment: @Lambie: Is this in agreement with or in opposition to my answer above?

Comment: @Cerberus I really don't know how to characterize it. I guess I would call it in addition to since you didn't provide it. My point does have merit.

Comment: @Lambie: I did not provide what?

Comment: @Cerberus You didn't provide, or provide for,  a terminating "thus". [god, I hate the internet for lack of suprasegmental features.] I do so prefer conversation. [sigh]. Just a point: I have noticed over the last 20 or or so years, that online questions may receive a bunch of answers, then, a particular answer (in this case,my answer) creates a warp in the answers because it is so different from others' answers. Like some sort of break, I dunno. (as in epistemological break) or mental warp.

Comment: @Lambie: I said, *"When it means "in this manner", it's perfectly fine at the end."*. Is that not "terminating"? Lovely cat, by the way. This is the first time I've noticed.

Comment: @Cerberus, I disagree that at the end of a sentence thus means: in this manner per se. Alas, poor Bootsie has left us (the most amazing street-and-house cat) and we now have Gerri-cat, a very indoor feline who goes for walks with me. I should probably change the picture. :)

Comment: @Lambie: Why do you disagree? Keep the picture: nothing wrong with honouring the dead.

Comment: @Cerberus Please read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

*I try to no overuse such conjunctions in the beginning of sentences, as for me, it seems to disrupt the “flow”.*

There is an equally good argument that the appropriate conjunction increases the flow of both reading and meaning.

I think it's difficult to improve on: "Most properties carry over directly, so we only need to discuss them for one case." More formally, you might use the passive voice: "Most properties carry over directly, so only one case needs to be discussed." (Or more crisply, "need be discussed.").

There is an old-fashioned but still meaningful idiom in English: ***It was ever thus.***

It normally follows a sentence describing a state of affairs that has no implied end-point, such as: "With each new technological breakthrough, the rich get richer and the poor stay poor."

Comment: I agree, “so” is a good connective and less invasive than “thus”, “therefore” or “hence”. I already use “so“ so much ...

Comment: “It was ever thus” is an example of the second meaning of “thus” given by Cerberus.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to make sense of this:
Most properties carry over directly. We only need to discuss them for one case thus.

The logical way to write it should be thus [deixis]:

Most properties carry over directly.
- Thus, we only need to discuss them for one case thus.
OR
- Therefore, we only need to discuss them for one case.
OR
- So, we only need to [etc.]
//

I would draw the nose thus:
[This is a placeholder]

"thus" can be used for purposes of deixis, as a deictic word referring to something a speaker is illustrating in reality.

[deixis or reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis)

Therefore and thus are otherwise placed at the head of a sentence. They are adverbs and point to what follows as being related to what preceded, usually to show a writer's or speaker's presenting some kind of logical result they come to (not necessarily "real logic").